# Shower valve either very hot or very cold - too sensitive

Tags: plumbing, shower

Basically, I'm trying to figure out if this requires replacing the whole shower valve.

Anyone know the cause?

[image]

Comment: What brand is this? You should first try to adjust/calibrate. If that fails, then 'rebuild' or replace the 'cartridge'. I think for the standard US shower valve replacement means opening up the wall. If you end up doing that you might want to try the European style 'bar' valve. The whole valve is external to the wall so future replacement does not require opening up the wall. The space between the supply lines for nearly all bar valves is 150 mm or 6 inches, but adjustable within a range. Some come with an integral spigot and diverter for shower or tub.